# Capturing repeated groups from a single Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse logs that may include one or more "FAULT" reports per line.
Then I need to extract (to simplify) the file name and the fault code for *each* occurrence.

I am struggling to find an elegant solution to retrieve all fault captures, though.

```py
    lines = [
        r"arbitrary/path/one.file(285): some unimportant text [FAULT: 1234], [FAULT: 4321]",
        ]

    pattern = (r'^\s*(?P<path>[\w\/\\\.]+)\(\d+\):\s+([^\[]+)'
               '((\[\s*FAULT:\s(?P<fault_code>\d{2,4})\])(,\s*)?)+$')

    for line in lines:
        for match in [m.groupdict() for m in re.finditer(pattern, line)]:
            print(f"path: {match['path']}; fault_code: {match['fault_code']}")
```

([Live](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zs23a2b4))

In the example above I'd expect to have two matches:

```
path: arbitrary/path/one.file; fault_code: 1234
path: arbitrary/path/one.file; fault_code: 4321
```

But I get only the longest lenght match:

```
path: arbitrary/path/one.file; fault_code: 4321
```

Would anyone have any good suggestions, please?

---

**Note:**

In my real problem, log is quite more complicated and there are more fields to extract both in common part and the fault specific part, but I tried to keep the example simple.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hadn't you got an error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'group'` with your current code?

Comment: Indeed. I was thinking more about a "conceptual" example but now I changed it to something that works. Thanks.

Comment: I would split this in something like pattern_line = (path)...(all_faults) and a second one inside for all faults

Comment: Thank you very much am2 and RomanPerekhrest. My final solution ended up being a mix of your suggestions. Unfortunately I cannot mark both for acceptance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split it into 2 Parts: First: Scan the line, second: scan the fault codes

```
import re

lines = [
    r"arbitrary/path/one.file(285): some unimportant text [FAULT: 1234], [FAULT: 4321]",
    r"arbitrary/path/second.file(285): some unimportant text [FAULT: 2345], [FAULT: 5432]",
    ]

pattern = (r'^\s*(?P<path>[\w\/\\\.]+)\(\d+\):\s+([^\[]+)'
           '(?P<all_faults>((\[\s*FAULT:\s(?P<fault_code>\d{2,4})\])(,\s*)?)+)$')

pattern_faults = r'((\[\s*FAULT:\s(?P<fault_code>\d{2,4})\])(,\s*)?)'

for line in lines:
    for match in [m.groupdict() for m in re.finditer(pattern, line)]:
        path = match['path']
        #print(f"path: {match['path']}; fault_code: {match['fault_code']}, {match['all_faults']}")
        for p in re.finditer(pattern_faults,match['all_faults']):
            fault_code = p.groupdict()['fault_code']

            print (f'path = {path} fault_code = {fault_code}')
```

Result:

```
path = arbitrary/path/one.file fault_code = 1234
path = arbitrary/path/one.file fault_code = 4321
path = arbitrary/path/second.file fault_code = 2345
path = arbitrary/path/second.file fault_code = 5432
```

If I work with Regexes I prefer something like

```
pattern_line = re.compile(r'^\s*'
    '(?P<path>[\w\/\\\.]+)' #Filename
    '(?P<linennumber>\(\d+\):)' #LineNumber
    '(?P<unimportant>\s+([^\[]+))' #unimportent Text
    '(?P<all_faults>((\[\s*FAULT:\s(\d{2,4})\])(,\s*)?)*)$'
    )
```

so for debugging you can find out easier, in which box your letters were put in

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that regex engine can't assign the same group name `fault_code` for dynamic, consecutive repeated groups. You can capture all the fault codes sequence for further sub-maching:

```
# added one additional fault code
lines = [
    r"arbitrary/path/one.file(285): some unimportant text [FAULT: 1234]"
    r", [FAULT: 4321], [FAULT: 0011]",
]

num_pat = re.compile(r'\d+')
fault_code_pat = r'\[\s*FAULT:\s\d{2,4}\]'
main_pat = re.compile(r'^\s*(?P<path>[\w\/\\\.]+)\(\d+\):\s+([^\[]+)'
                      rf'(?P<fault_codes>{fault_code_pat}(?:,\s*{fault_code_pat})*)$')

for line in lines:
    for m in re.finditer(main_pat, line):
        for f_code in num_pat.findall(m.group('fault_codes')):
            print(f"path: {m.group('path')}; fault_code: {f_code}")
```

---

```
path: arbitrary/path/one.file; fault_code: 1234
path: arbitrary/path/one.file; fault_code: 4321
path: arbitrary/path/one.file; fault_code: 0011
```